# Replace occurrences in specific pattern

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a JSON file with text keys, for my code base, in the format

```
"abc.xyz": "plain text",
"abc.xyz.lmn": "plain text",
"abc.xyz.lmn.qrs.hij": "plain text",
```

Where `xxx` are keys of the format [a-zA-Z].[a-zA-Z] e.g. "app.feature.component.title" or similar.

I then have references to these all over the code base.

```
someComponent(title: "xyz.abc.ijk")
```

I am trying to substitute all the dots `.` in the keys with a dash `-` to get:
`xxx-xxx-xxx` both in the code base and in the JSON, i.e. the surrounding structure might be different.

Something like this, but with the number `xxx` groups varying between keys:

```
\"([a-zA-Z]+(\.)[a-zA-Z]+)+
```

I am using my editor (Xcode) so I think the regex flavour is ICU

Comment: do you need regex or could you just use replace ([XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))?

Comment: It seems OP does need a RegEx, replace in most editors can only swap one string for another (unless you supply a RegEx parameter, in which case it will do what OP requested). Perfectly reasonable question imo.

Comment: What should happen when finding `"abc.wxyz.lmn.qrs.hij"`, i.e. with a group that has 4 letters instead of 3. Should *any* point be replaced, or none?

Comment: @trincot as demonstrated by the "app.feature.component.title" example, it seems OP can have sets of more than 3 characters.

Comment: I will assume that then.

Comment: Yes as @Xiddoc says they can be of varying length, I was a bit unsure about how to express that in a generic way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use look ahead assertion so to avoid matching letters that you still need to match for a next replacement. That look ahead assertion could also check that the sequence is ended by a double quote. This could be enough for checking that the target is quoted, without actually asserting that the sequence *started* with a quote:

Find: `\.(?=[A-Za-z.]+")`

Replace with: `-`

If two consecutive dots should be left unaltered, then:

Find: `\b\.\b(?=[A-Za-z.]+")`

Comment: Thanks, I see, that was part of my struggle that I specified both starting and end \" This works! I guess it could be more restrictive as it also seems to capture all the dots in an ellipsis`...` , but luckily those are few in the code base.

Comment: If you don't want to replace dots when they are consecutive, then do: `\b\.\b(?=[A-Za-z.]+")`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use below pattern

- Search pattern: `(?<="|\.)(\w+?)\.`
- Substitution value: `$1-`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/PGnCG0/1

Comment: This is problematic as it also captures `someObject.function` in the source code, of which I have a few. I need to to be within `"key.identifier.value"`

Comment: I've thought about that case, but only try to suggest a pattern without look-around. Anyway, I've edited my answer.